# Dotnet core 3.0 not showing in visual studio only 2.1 and 2.2 showing

Tags: asp.net, model-view-controller, sdk, visual-studio-2019

Hi I'm trying to use the latest .NET Core 3.0 but it's not showing up in Visual Studio when creating project. I have tried everything I know (see screenshot) anything else I'm missing?

[Visual studio need 3.0 to show here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/shwOO.png)

[evidence that version 3.0 is installed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/orHDW.png)

[system variable showing path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7aG7D.png)

[tick the use previews of .Net core in VS still not working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fuzw2.png)

[version of VS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hxh3C.png)

[evidence that VS is upto date](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yaUz0.png)

Answer (score 1):

As you can see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/core/windows-prerequisites?tabs=netcore30), dotnet core 3.0 development requires Visual Studio 2019 version 16.3 or higher.